# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 36640012 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 31MB until OOM

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I'm new to android and currently working on an android project. For this app, I tried to add AdMob for that. after that, there was an error like in the Title.

In previously I faced this OutOfMemory error in this same app and I was able to solve this by adding the following properties into the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

After that, I added an AdMob banner ad for the application. Then was an error like this.

**"Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 71296 > 65536)"**

That was also able to fix after adding the following properties into the `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
multiDexEnabled true
```

But when I try to run the application, I faced the following error. When I Search, I only
able to see the following solution(add following properties into the `AndroidManifest.xml`)

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

But I have already done those things as I mentioned above. So what should I need to do? I will add the stack trace here

```
    E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 36640012 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 32MB until OOM"
        D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
        D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
        E/art: li.han, Prepare to dump hprof for OOM Error !
        li.han, Directory [/data/misc/hprofs] could not be write !
        E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.handy, PID: 31817
        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 36640012 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 32MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:837)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:656)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1037)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4056)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1991)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1973)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:409)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api21Impl.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:862)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:480)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:147)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:135)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:63)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:82)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:199)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:119)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1563)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1614)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.handy.time.Sleep.onCreate(Sleep.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the OOM so we can see where the large heap allocation comes from. BTW: It is bad style to have important information only in the title. The title is dedicated to summarize the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Robert, I forgot to add it in previously, but i had added it

Comment: The layout that is loaded seems to contain a large image. You should better reduce it's size and memory footprint.